# How to deprecate a custom Exception in python while maintaining backwards compatibility?

Tags: python, oop, exception, deprecated

I have two old codebase files:
File `a.py` and file `try.py`, respectively:

```
class A(BaseException):
  pass
```

and in `try.py`

```
from a import A
from c import raise_exception_of_A()
try:
    raise_exception_of_A()
except A:
  print('Exception handled')
except Exception:
  print('Panic')
```

now a new version of `class A` was developed it file `b.py`

```
class A(BaseException):
  pass
```

**And a new version of `raise_exception_of_A()` was developed in file `c.py` that raises an exception from `class A` of `b.py`**

Now I would like to mark the usage of the `class A` in `a.py` as deprecated while maintaining the backwards compatibility with `try.py` meaning I cannot modify this file. I can modify only file `a.py` and `b.py`.

Is this possible?

As to my tests and knowledge `except` uses internally `isinstance()` and it would mean that it compares

```
from a import A
from b import A as NewA
a = A()
isinstance(a, NewA) # fails
```

One solution would be to just remove the `class A` in `a.py` and on top of the file add
from b import A
And use it as a bridge but then I would loose the warning message and that is not desired.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure there's anything *to* deprecate. Do your users ever instantiate `a.A` directly, or are they just catching exceptions raised by `raise_exception_of_A`?

Comment: yes, is instantiated through the codebase. In this just particular case it is used for exception

Comment: Then I don't think there's anything to do, except maybe raise a deprecation warning if you try to import `a` at all. Does the exception have any structure at all, aside from its name?

Comment: Sorry @chepner but did not understand well what you meant with "Does exception have any structure at all" could you elaborate

Comment: Does it have attributes, methods, etc, or do you only care about it for its name? If the latter, the user doesn't care where it comes from or how it gets defined; you can change it at will as long as the name looks the same to the user. (Keep in mind that changing what it inherits from may fall under "changing the name" with regard to its use.)

Comment: Yes, it does in fact have attributes and methods, and they differ from `a.A` to `b.B` I am starting to think this question goes down to, `how to make a parent object appear to be an instance of a child class` or `make two classes appear of the same type` and currently am researching that route